# Using both junit assertions and mockito verification

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm using Junit in conjunction with Mockito. I used mockito's verify method + junit assertion to do complete verification. Is this not desirable? Should we use one or the other but not both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using both.

Mockito's `verify` is used to assert a method was called (with the expected arguments) on the given mock.

JUnit's `assertXYZ` is used to assert that some result has the expected value.

Both are valid verifications, and if both are relevant, both should be used.

For example, consider the following (admittedly artificial) situation:

You have an interface that performs some mathematical calculation:

```
public interface ValueProducer {
    public int getValue(int val);
}
```

And a class that doubles any result produced by it:

```
public class Doubler {
    public static int doubleThatResult (ValueProducer producer, int val) {
        return 2 * producer.getValue(val);
    }
}
```

Testing it would require to assert two things:

1. That `getValue` was properly called
2. That the result is doubled

So, e.g.:

```
public class DoublerTest {

    @Test
    public void testDoubleThatResult() throws Exception {
        int value = 7; // Or any other value
        int returnMock = 13; // Or any other value

        ValueProducer producerMock = mock(ValueProducer.class);
        when(producerMock.getValue(value)).thenReturn(returnMock);

        int actual = Doubler.doubleThatResult(producerMock, value);

        verify(producerMock);
        assertEquals(26, actual);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, though _in this example_ the verification is slightly redundant because the call could be inferred from the result of 26—the 13 almost certainly came because the stubbed method call actually happened.

Comment: @JeffBowman I admit this example is extremely artificial, but when it comes to unit tests I prefer to pile on (seemingly) redundant assertions over missing potential bugs. With this example, implementing `Doubler.doubleThatResult` as `return 26;` would pass the test if you remove the mock's verification. It's **completely** artificial, but it demonstrates the point I was trying to make.

Comment: True, and I can easily imagine a slightly-different less-redundant example—and at a certain point it's a reasonable tradeoff, especially if tested behavior is complex, sensitive, or legacy code. More than anything I was just paraphrasing the [Javadoc for `verify`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)) ("Although it is possible to verify a stubbed invocation, usually it's **just redundant**.") and the [article to which it links](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling).

Answer (score 1):

Mureinik's answer is absolutely correct—assertions and verifications are complementary, and work quite well together—but doing both for a single behavior may be redundant.

The goal is usually to express the test in the most flexible and implementation-agnostic way possible. State testing (with assertions) is often the most appropriate choice, in that sense: it doesn't matter which methods were called as long as the resulting state is correct. A Mockito verification, while possible, may introduce brittleness (where the code behaves correctly but the test is broken). Mockito itself warns of this in [`verify(T)`'s Javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)) and [the linked article by Mockito's creator Szczepan Faber](http://monkeyisland.pl/2008/04/26/asking-and-telling).

This redundancy is certainly not the worst thing: It does test a property of the system, and may be a worthwhile endeavor in testing interactions with sensitive, legacy, third-party, or frequently-changing dependencies. If the interaction is unimportant, though, these extra verifications may come at the expense of brittleness.

Other times, confirming correct behavior means testing side-effects—for example, ensuring that `someSystem.reset()` was called, or testing a cache by verifying a provider was NOT called. These are perfect examples for verification, because the interaction with the external service is critical testable behavior. In some of these cases, Mockito verifications are the *only* way to make the correct assertions.

Many test cases are a combination of the above, so feel free to use assertions and verifications freely together; just remember that state testing is often sufficient and preferable.